# Something weird with writing file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, io, remote-server

So, this is a problem:
I have a several textboxes, and I need to serialize them.
This is how I am doing this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = "d:/DZHosts/LocalUser/YoYoZ/LOL/Reports";

        string[] s = new string[4];
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "Report #" + i + ".rep", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        s[0] = TextBox1.Text;
        s[1] = TextBox2.Text;
        s[2] = TextBox3.Text;
        s[3] = TextBox4.Text;
        bf.Serialize(fs, s);
        fs.Close();
        i++;
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        Label1.Text = "Complete!";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Response.Redirect("http://LOL/Default.aspx");
    }
```

But when i press write it says:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Report #0.rep' is denied.
```

Why is it not trying to write to proper directory?

Comment: Is this code running from IIS?

Comment: In any case use \\ instead of /

Answer (score 1):

why are you trying to change the Environment.CurrentDirectory? you would only want to reference that if you expect that it might change in different instances. if you just want to read/write from a predefined path why not call

FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:/DZHosts/LocalUser/YoYoZ/LOL/Reports/Report #" + i + ".rep", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = "d:/DZHosts/LocalUser/YoYoZ/LOL/Reports";
```

is not working as you expect. Try this

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Temp"); 
string whereami = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Comment: If this is an ASP.NET website with default security in IIS, it's guaranteed not to have access to any folder outside the site root. There's nothing wrong with using `/` as the path separator - you can try it. The poster's problem is not how the path is written (assuming it exists).

Answer (score 0):

Your website (it's app pool) is running under the IUSR account which only has access to the site's root folder, nothing outside that. If you need to access other folders outside of your site's root, you need to add the IUSR account to those folders.

In general, it's a bad idea to access system folders, though, since it gives a potential attacker a way to access and potentially modify system files - if your server is hacked.

You'd be better off using a local folder inside your site's root folder to store report output. This way all files of your site will be under a single root folder and you don't have to worry about managing other folders on the disk. If you ever need to use shared hosting (where you don't control the server), this is also your only option - on shared hosting services, a site may not access anything outside its root folder.

To get the physical path to your site's root folder, use:

```
string sPath = Server.MapPath("/");
```

Comment: That path, that I am using, my hosting gave it to me. But ASP.net is not working with it,

Answer (score 0):

It would be a very bad idea for your program to have access to folders under the Windows install directory.  In fact, if your program is not running as a member of the Administrators group, it will not have access by default.  Again by default (and for good reasons), ASP.Net programs run with a minimum set of privileges.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that i tried to upload raw site, not packaged properly. I used package option in Project menu, and then complete site was in obj\Release\Package. Thanks everyone who tried to help!